# Erro interno payments sandbox mercado pago

Tags: api

Boa noite.
Estou fazendo integração, sandbox, no mercado pago e estou tomando o seguinte erro:

```
{
"message": "internal_error",
"error": null,
"status": 500,
"cause": []
}
```

O body da transação:

```
{
"transaction_amount": 1,
"token": "{{TOKEN_CREDT_CARD}}",
"description": "Notebook",
"payment_method_id": "master",
"installments": 1,
"payer": {
    "email": "test_user_26305340@testuser.com",
    "entity_type": "guest",
    "type": null,
    "id": "{{ID_PAYER}}",
    "identification": {
        "type": null,
        "number": null
    },
    "first_name": "first_name",
    "last_name": "last_name"
},
"order": {
    "type": "mercadopago",
    "id": 1
}

}
```

Estou gerando o token do cartão de crédito da seguinte forma:

```
{
"email": "test_user_26305340@testuser.com",
"cardNumber": "5031**********351",
"securityCode": "999",
"expirationYear": "2999",
"expirationMonth": "02"
}
```

cardNumber: Obtive nos exemplos de cartão do próprio mercadopago.
O intrigante é que mesmo com esse erro, se eu tentar novamente, a api diz que o token do cartão é inválido, como se a transação tivesse tido exito.

Estou testando no POSTMAN.

Comment: Eu também estou vendo este erro aqui.

Comment: Também acontece comigo, mas volta após um tempo